# show FlatList ItemSeparatorComponent when no data exist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to show `FlatList` like this ,each item renderer has a `ItemSeparatorComponent` even if there is no data for them.

I guess I can add empty data to the `dataProvider`.

And I want to know if I can set some attributes of `FlatList` to make it work?

[image]

Comment: provide some code!

Answer (score 0):

Its depended on how you bind your flat list data. if you have got empty item so you can render it. just don't forget to use `minHeight` style for the view of your rendered item of flat list because if you dont use it you will not see the separator.